# Swift 2: App crashes during rotation

Tags: uitableview, swift2, nsarray, uiinterfaceorientation

i have reloaded the view that contains table view. But when i keep on rotating the table view frequently the app crashes saying:
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason**: '**8 Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x7fdd5d460250> was mutated while being enumerated.'**

I have implemented a simple table view with its delegates.
Can anyone suggest what actually this means.

Comment: Just make sure your Array is preloaded before rendering table , let's say in willappear...

Comment: @user3344236 Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

looks like on rotate you are reloading the dataSource and while doing so your array is not fully populated and you are trying to change the array while its still have a reference somewhere else.